# Java Graphics not drawing anything

Tags: java, swing, graphics, jframe, jpanel

So, I'm trying to make a simple Pong program in java. Right now, it should just open a window, display a button ("start") and output to the console if you press the button. It opens the window, but does not draw the button. However, if you click on the area that I specified, it does register that you clicked and print to the console.

Here's my code.

The JPanel that is opened in the window:

```
public class Menu extends JPanel {

Font garamond = new Font("Garamond", Font.PLAIN, 20);

public Menu() {

    addMouseListener(new Mouse());

}

public void draw() {
    Graphics g = getGraphics();
    g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    g.drawRect(0, 0, 100, 100);
    g.setFont(garamond);
    g.setColor(Color.WHITE);
    g.drawString("Start", 10, 10);
    g.dispose();
}
```

The "Mouse" class that registers your clicks:

```
public class Mouse extends MouseAdapter {

public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
    if (e.getX() >= 0 && e.getX() <= 100 && e.getY() >= 0 && e.getY() <= 100) {
        Frame.buttonStart();
    }
}
```

And finally the "Frame" class that opens the window and displays the panel:

```
public class Frame {

static JFrame frame = new JFrame("Java Pong");

public static void initialize() {

    frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    frame.setSize(500, 400);
    frame.setLocation(100, 100);
    frame.setVisible(true); 
    setMode("menu");

}

public static void setMode(String Mode) {

    switch (Mode) {
    case "menu":
        Menu menu = new Menu();
        frame.getContentPane().add(menu, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        menu.draw();
        break;
    default:
        break;
    }

}

public static void buttonStart() {

    System.out.println("yeh button pressed");

}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should override `paintComponent()` to perform your custom drawing.  Draw on the `Graphics` object passed in to it.

In addition, you should perform all manipulations of Swing components on the Event Dispatch Thread, with use of `SwingUtilities.invokeAndWait()` or `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()`.  That includes instantiating and configuring UI components.

Also, if you want a button then you will get a big leg up from using a `JButton` instead of rolling your own.

*Edited to add:*

Example of using `SwingUtilities.invokeAdWait()`:

```
SwingUtilities.invokeAdWait(
    new Runnable() {
        @Override public void run() {
            // the work to be performed by the EDT goes here
            Frame.frame.pack();
            Frame.frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
);
```

You can probably get away with doing much of the initial setup in your main thread as long as you use `invokeAndWait()` when you initially display the GUI.  After that you should probably just let the main thread die.

Comment: Thanks, overriding paintComponent() worked!  Also, what are invokeAndWait/invokeLater? How would I use these?

Comment: You should use `invokeAndWait()` or `invokeLater()` because otherwise it is very hard to ensure proper synchronization between your main thread and the EDT.  Without proper synchronization, any number of strange behaviors may be exhibited.  I'll update my answer with an example.